# How to calculate pair wise distances between labeled components (binary image) in opencv (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, nearest-neighbor

I have binary image, that I show here:

[image]

I succesfully calculated centroids and stats of all white dots in this image by using opencv function: connectedComponentsWithStats, info link here:

[connectedComponentsWithStats](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae57b028a2b2ca327227c2399a9d53241)

Now I have to calculate all distances between all white dots (pair-wise) distances. My question is:

What is the easiest way to calculate pair-wise distances of white dots in opencv (c++)? I have read k-Nearest Neighbour in Python but I don't know how to implement that in c++. After distances calculated, I must color out every two dots that are closer than some value, for example, if two dots are closer than 10 px, they should be marked red (green otherwise)

Comment: The easiest way is to do two for loops on the list of centroids and calculate the euclidean distance between each pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to do it by yourself using two loops and standard euclidean distance formula. The coloring could probably done with [`setTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#a16cb9be32213df86f3b55ec131abff70) with mask set where values match current loop indices

```
cv::Mat centorids, connectedComponentsLabels;
connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectedComponentsLabels, stats, centroids, 8, CV_32S);
cv::Mat resultsImage = cv::Mat::zeros(connectedComponentsLabels.size(), CV_8UC3);
resultsImage.setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), connectedComponentsLabels != 0); //precolor all points green, so that red coloring can override it
for (int i = 1; i < centroids.rows - 1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < centroids.rows; ++j)
    {
        auto vec = cv::Point2d(centroids.at<double>(i, 0), centroids.at<double>(i, 1)) - 
                   cv::Point2d(centroids.at<double>(j, 0), centroids.at<double>(j, 1));
        double distSquared = vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y;
        if (distSquared > 100) //compare with 10 squared to avoid slow sqrt for distance
        {   //do the coloring red here
            resultsImage.setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), connectedComponentsLabels == i);
            resultsImage.setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), connectedComponentsLabels == j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `CV_BGR`, it's a macro of the old C api. You can use `cv::Scalar` instead (note that the order is BGR, however).

Comment: @Miki, actually, macro was [`CV_RGB`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=cv_rgb), but point taken.

Comment: Oh yes, sure... ;)

Comment: This is very good suggestion but with your code I have a problem. Code: 'centroids.size()' returns me [2 X 11] matrix and I get an error when try to type : 'centroids.size() - 1'  ERROR: No operator - matches these operands : operand types are: cv::Size - Int. How can i fix this?

Comment: @skoda23 documentation for `connectedComponentsWithStats` you linked to mentions that the `centroids` are set into a `Mat` that has x in column 0 and y in column 1, each component is in its own row; try to enumerate rows of a `Mat` instead of the `vector` like I did

Comment: And also... you assumed that connectedComponentsLabels is the output from connectedComponentsWIthStats? What type of output should connectedComponentsLabels be? Should it be ''stats'' matrix? Or It should be fourth coloumn of ''stats''  matrix?

Comment: @skoda23 I meant main output: "labels"

Comment: Ok..I'm trying to understand that...can I ask for additional information what exactly does it mean to enumerate rows of Mat instead of the vector? Know that I am new in c++...

Comment: @skoda23 please see my edited answer, I think it should now work as is

Comment: The main output of connectedComponentsWithStats returns me the number of labels = 11. This is (integer). My code: 'int numberOfLabels = connectedComponentsWithStats(image, labeledImage, stats, centroids, 8, CV_32S)'

Comment: @skoda23 `connectedComponentsLabels` is `Mat` that `connectedComponentsWithStats` returns in a parameter named *"labels"*

Comment: I used your new code. After code is executed, the Mat resultImage is UIN8 3X0X0 matrix, and when I want to show it with namedWIndow() I cannot see anything :S what can be wrong here?

Comment: @skoda23 comment in the second line of code suggests that you should call `connectedComponentsWithStats` to initialize `Mat`s declared in the first line. Did you do that? "As is" in my previous comments does not mean copy-paste-run, but rather copy-paste-think-editabit-run

Comment: This is how I did it: 'cv::Mat centorids, connectedComponentsLabels;
 connectedComponentsLabels = connectedComponentsWithStats(image, labeledImage, stats, centroids, 8, CV_32S);' Then it comes all your code. And after it I want to display resultsImage, but program crashes If I want to show image using namesWIndow and imshow

Comment: @skoda23, ok, I edited the answer once more to show how to call the `connectedComponentsWithStats` correctly

Comment: Thank you very much this was the exactly what I was looking for! You are the best!! Thanks!

Comment: I studied your code and there is everything clear only the line : `auto vec = Point2d(centroids.at<double>(i, 0), centroids.at<double>(i, 1)) - Point2d(centroids.at<double>(j, 0), centroids.at<double>(j, 1)); ` Is there any special reason why you choose type auto of variable vec ? Isn't it easyer to just go like: `double vec = ( (centroids.at<double>(i, 0) + centroids.at<double>(i, 1)) - ((centroids.at<double>(j, 0), centroids.at<double>(j, 1)))` ?

Comment: For example the result of calculating distance is the same as if I code it like this: `double raz1, raz2;
   raz1 = centroids.at<double>(i, 0) - centroids.at<double>(j, 0);
   raz2 = centroids.at<double>(i, 1) - centroids.at<double>(j, 1);
   double dist2 = sqrt( pow(raz1,2) + pow(raz2,2) );`

Comment: @skoda23 `auto` is (in a large simplification) a keyword that in contemporary c++ tells the compiler to substitute it with a type name it deduces from the context. In this case (subtraction of two `cv::Point2d`) `vec`'s type is `cv::Point2d`, not double. Using `auto` is for simplification, sometimes clarity, and a bit of abstraction

Comment: if you prefer different implementation and it works, go for it

Comment: Thank you again also for this explanation! I really appriciate your work here!

Comment: @slawekwin can you suggest me how to optimize speed of calculation?? In my image processing application, pairwise distances take me the most of processing time. Since there is a lot of anomalies that can accur, the calculation is to slow...